# Make Tween Animating Lines From Inside Out

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have an image of lines, as depicted in the small photo below, that I would like to animate with a Tween to make it appear as though it is being drawn from the middle outwards.
[image]

I have come up with a good way of doing this, at least theoretically. I have set up my image dimensions and absolute position to be where I want it at the end. I have contained it inside a small absolute positioned div with auto margins and zero width/height that increases with a Tween, so that it expands outwards from the middle slowly and therefore as the container expands it looks like the image is being "drawn" outwards.

However, I have a problem, as demonstrated by the image below. The lines image is positioned relative to the containing div, in the centre, rather than the body (and I understand that this is because they are both absolute positioned). How do I position the child element in the container relative to the body rather than the container, without removing it as a child (there are other layers of my background that would be covered by this div expanding)?

Here is my code:

```
<div id='cover'><div id='child'></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#cover {
    background-image: url('/images/slide21/bg_layer3.png');
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: none;
    height: 46vh;
    width: 78.5vw;
    z-index: -8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0vw;      // these are coordinates that should
    right: 0;      // be positioned relative to the
    left: -0.5vw;  // body not container
    opacity: 1;
}

#container {
    width: 0;  // as animation occurs, width and
    height: 0; // height increase to 100%
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -5;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to position the line drawing relative to the body?

Comment: I want to make it look like the lines are being drawn from inside, where the dots are, outwards. I am not sure how to do this given that I have multiple background divs that I do not want to cover with a gradient pseudo element... So the solution I thought was to make almost a mask in the middle increase in width and height outwards whilst keeping the inner image (lines) fixed. Can you think of another way?